# jQuery DOM change screws my CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have this:

```
if($('.content', wrapper).length === 0)
   $(data[current].content).appendTo(wrapper);
else
   $('.content', wrapper).replaceWith($(data[current].content));

var el = $('.content', wrapper);
```

which is working, but this code, which should do the same:

```
var el = ($('.content', wrapper).length === 0) 
           ? $(data[current].content).appendTo(wrapper) 
           : $('.content', wrapper).replaceWith($(data[current].content));
```

is screwing up my CSS.

`el` seems to be the same in both cases, but for some weird reason my animations that follow after this go wrong, most likely because of some CSS changes...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is .replaceWith what you want?  I believe that will return the old content, not the newly replaced content.

Comment: well I want `$('.content', wrapper)` (the replaced element). Isn't that what replaceWith returns in my case?

Comment: I think it will return the content that was replaced(and is no longer in the DOM).  from the jQuery docs: "it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not the new element that has replaced it."

Comment: you're right. I found `replaceAll` http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/, which works, and it seems to return the new content. thanks, you should post your comments as a answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.replaceWith will return the content that was replaced(and is no longer in the DOM). From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

> it must be noted that the original
>   jQuery object is returned. This object
>   refers to the element that has been
>   removed from the DOM, not the new
>   element that has replaced it.